# How to call generic method in a nested generic struct?

Tags: generics, rust, struct

I need to deal with an enum from an external Rust crate that comprises different data types:

```
pub enum Variables {
    Float(f32),
    Double(f64)
}
```

I want to convert this to my own generic data structure and wrap it in a different struct to enrich it with metadata:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct MyWrapperVar<T> {
    num: i8,
    id: String,
    var: MyVar<T>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct MyVar<T> {
    name: String,
    value: T,
}
```

Instances of `MyWrapperVar` will be serialized and sent to different consumers. To facilitate the serialization, I have created multiple `new` functions:

```
impl MyVar<f32> {
    fn new(name: &str, value: f32) -> Self {
        Self {
            name: name.to_string(),
            value,
        }
    }
}

impl MyVar<f64> {
    fn new(name: &str, value: f64) -> Self {
        Self {
            name: name.to_string(),
            value,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> MyWrapperVar<T> {
    fn new(
        num: i8,
        id: &str,
        variable_name: &str,
        variable_value: T,
    ) -> MyWrapperVar<T> {
        Self {
            num,
            id: id.to_string(),
            var: MyVar::<T>::new(variable_name, variable_value),
        }
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that I could simply match on `Variables` and then call my generic `MyWrapperVar::new` function:

```
fn main() {
    let var1 = Variables::Float(0.1);
    match var1 {
        Variables::Float(v) => {
            let bla = MyWrapperVar::new(0, "bla", "var1", v);
        }
        Variables::Double(v) => {
            let bla = MyWrapperVar::new(0, "bla", "var1", v);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this does not seem to work as I get the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `new` found for struct `MyVar<T>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:42:30
   |
9  | pub struct MyVar<T> {
   | ------------------- function or associated item `new` not found for this struct
...
42 |             var: MyVar::<T>::new(variable_name, variable_value),
   |                              ^^^ function or associated item not found in `MyVar<T>`
   |
   = note: the function or associated item was found for
           - `MyVar<f32>`
           - `MyVar<f64>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
```

See the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78c51c05d590913477bfda9b79637eec) for an MRE.

Comment: Nit: [If you need `String`, you should take `String`, not `&str` and convert it](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/flexibility.html#caller-decides-where-to-copy-and-place-data-c-caller-control). Or at least, take `impl Into<String>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you for this important note! Greatly appreciated! I made this 'mistake' way too often :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyVar::new` is **not** defined for all possible values of `T` only for 2 very specific ones, `f32` and `f64`, but `MyWrappedVar` is implemented for *every* value of `T`, including values such as `&str`, `String`, ..., so you can't call `MyVar::new` with an unconstrained `T`. The solution is to define `MyWrappedVar::new` for the same constrained set as `MyVar::new`, that is only for `f32` and for `f64`.

```rust
impl MyWrapperVar<f32> {
    fn new(
        num: i8,
        id: &str,
        variable_name: &str,
        variable_value: f32,
    ) -> MyWrapperVar<f32> {
        Self {
            num,
            id: id.to_string(),
            var: MyVar::<f32>::new(variable_name, variable_value),
        }
    }
}
impl MyWrapperVar<f64> {
    fn new(
        num: i8,
        id: &str,
        variable_name: &str,
        variable_value: f64,
    ) -> MyWrapperVar<f64> {
        Self {
            num,
            id: id.to_string(),
            var: MyVar::<f64>::new(variable_name, variable_value),
        }
    }
}
```

Or to actually implement `MyVar::new` for *every* `T`:

```rust
impl<T> MyVar<T> {
    fn new(name: &str, value: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            name: name.to_string(),
            value,
        }
    }
}
```